# Can Bioinformatics be used in developing a marketable product?

Tags: independent-researcher, bioinformatics

As we all know computer science, electrical engineering, etc. knowhows can be used in developing software and electronics/electrical products that can be sold to end-users (B2C).

Can bioinformatics be used to develop such products (except for drug discovery)?

Or, is it just about scientific/academic research meant for B2B clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bioinformatics is currently used by many different commercial companies.
Applications include drug development as you mentioned, but also other areas such as sequencing and meta-barcoding, toxicology, ag chemical development, and personalized medicine.

A search on Indeed.com on 29 May 2022  for "Bioinformatics Scientist" (results link [here](https://www.indeed.com/jobs?q=Bioinformatics%20Scientist&aceid&gclid=CjwKCAjws8yUBhA1EiwAi_tpET5SICkqq5ICn-uE1Rc3FNik9j4eOzMiFpddvC_9LEts9gIZd85aoBoCkLwQAvD_BwE&from=mobRdr&utm_source=%2Fm%2F&utm_medium=redir&utm_campaign=dt&vjk=e4c7688a3f285972)) shows many commercial companies hiring including well known commercial companies such as Johnson and Johnson and Illumina.